# How to start the download of remote big files directly?

Tags: php, stream, download, fopen

I'm trying to pass a large file from an external API to the user, (think 100MB or more)

Currently, I'm using a bit of a paranoid script (due to failures from the past) to get the script downloading ASAP.

By 'downloading', I only mean the download trigger on the browser, not the actual downloading of the file. Just the point where user can select where (s)he wants to save the file.

```
set_time_limit(0);

apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
ob_implicit_flush(1);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Cache-Control: private');

ob_flush();
flush();

$fh = fopen($external_api_url, 'rb');
while(!feof($fh))
{
    echo fread($fh, 512);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
fclose($fh);
```

Using this script, it still takes 20 seconds for a 50mb file before the download popup shows up, and much longer with bigger files.

Is there any way to start the stream faster?

EDIT:
I've also tried fpassthru() and readfile() but these take 40 seconds for the same 50mb file, making me think this way is better. I've also played around with different read sizes (512, 256, 64, couple of others) but I didn't notice a difference)

Comment: If you have PHP 5, did you try `$contents = stream_get_contents($fh); echo $contents;` or `file_get_contents(...)` instead of your `while` loop? Also, fread() actually encourages you to read 8192 bytes at once, as that is the chunk size.

Comment: @Arthur Wouldn't stream_get_contents and file_get_contents wait for the whole file to be downloaded in PHP before sending it to the user? Also I wasn't aware of teh 8192 bute chunk size, which would explain why the different values (all under this number) I tried gave the same result. Is there a way to lower the chunk-size?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is taking so long for your browser to trigger the download dialog, is due to the API taking that long to return its first chunk of data, for example they might be reading the whole file to memory before starting to send the data to you, which would explain why longer files take longer to start even though you always try to write the first 512 bytes as quickly as possible.

I tried to simulate it locally by reading from a local file, but having a `sleep(5);` statement right before your `while` loop.

I was able to get Google Chrome to start the download before any data, by **omitting** the `header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');` line, while still issuing a `flush();` call before attempting to read the file. (You are already doing this second part)

This however doesn't seem to work with Firefox 3.6, so you might need different gimmicks for different browsers, unless you can predict the first character of a file (Take a look at [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) and echo that before anything, subsequently removing it from the beginning of your first `fread()` call.

I hope it helps! But basically the external API is screwing you over.

Comment: The external API is screwing me over since the moment I had to work for it. :P But thanks for the anwser, I'll try it ASAP and report back :)

Comment: It seems to work great, I did notice the same issue with FireFox and ommiting the content-type header, FireFox will download it as a html file even though it's something else... Maybe I can send that header later...